# EmberJS hasMany relationship and Fixtures

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm learning EmberJS and need some help.

I have two models: Catalog and CatalogCourses. Catalog has many CatalogCourses.
I'm just trying to test this relationship with some fixtures.

When I load a record of Catalog the relationship fixtures (CatalogCourses) doesn't load.
I've been stuck on this for a couple hours, and I think it should be simple to do this, so I'm asking for your help.

Here are the models:

```
App.Catalog = DS.Model.extend({
  year: DS.attr('string'),
  catalogCourses: DS.hasMany('catalog_course')
});

App.CatalogCourse = DS.Model.extend({
  catalog: DS.belongsTo('catalog')
});
```

And here are the Fixtures:

```
App.Catalog.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    year: '2014',
    catalog_courses: [ 1 ]
  }
];

App.CatalogCourse.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    catalog: 1
  }
];
```

And here is a Fiddle of me trying to simply list that relationship:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/75/

I'm using ember v1.5.0, ember-data v1.0.0-beta.7, handlebars v1.3.0 and jQuery 1.11.0

I tried using the `{async: true}` option aswell, but the problem persists.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Besides the naming convetion (see the accepted answer) , I was also having some trouble with coffeescript: the last line of my catalog.coffee file wasn't being compiled, therefore there were no relationships at all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is just in your fixtures. You name your model attribute `catalogCourses`, yet in your fixture setup you use `catalog_courses`. If you change `catalog_courses` to `catalogCourses` in your fixture setup, it works.

Mind you that for using fixtures with relations, you need to use the `{ async: true }` flag on the relationship definition in your models.

See this jsbin with a working example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gedew/2/edit