# Double definition required in belongsTo and hasMany with FIXTURES?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm testing out a very simple model relationship. I'm using the Fixture adapter before I switch to a true back-end. Somewhat following from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693925/where-did-my-data-get-stuck-in-ember/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558825/emberjs-hasmany-relationship-and-fixtures), I've found I need to define *both sides* of the relationship in each Fixture.

Is that a restriction of the Fixture adapter or will the backend/database also have to store both sides (which is non-standard for something like SQL)?

Models:

```
// app/models/comment.js
...
export default DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  //post: DS.belongsTo('post', {async: true})  // async only needed on one side - true??
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
}).reopenClass({
FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Text of the comment goes right in here',
      author: 'Fred',
      post: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'TWO 2222 comment two here',
      author: 'Barney',
      post: 1
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: 'third comment here',
      author: 'Wilma',
      post: 2
    },
...

// app/models/post.js
...
export default DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async: true})
}).reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Post ONE - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur risus.',
      comments: [1,2]  // Why is this required??
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Post TWO - consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed gravida faucibus risus.',
      comments: [3,4]  // Why is this required?
    },
...
```

My ember info:

- Ember Inspector 1.8.2
- Ember 1.12.0
- Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.18
- jQuery
  1.11.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a restriction on Fixtures.

I would recommend using [jQuery ajaxMock](http://plugins.jquery.com/ajaxmock/) instead of Fixtures - then you can start using the serialisers/adapters you will be using in production and also be more confident with how your code will work.

Comment: Thanks @jmurphyau - cool plugin, I'll have a look. I'm actually thinking I might just hook up my sample to a backend now. Or maybe just switch now to [SANE](http://sanestack.com/) which hooks up both back and front end setup with its "generate resource" command.

Comment: Yes, mocking has several advantages. Another option, use pretender via [ember-cli-mirage](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage).